# как изменить форму массива python

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть массив:

```
[    [0],    [1],    [10],   [11],  [100],   [101],   [110],   [111], ...]
```

как мне сделать чтобы было так:

```
[    0     1    10    11   100   101   110   111  1000  1001  1010  1011
  1100  1101  1110  1111 10000 10001 10010 10011 10100 10101 10110 10111
 11000 11001 11010 11011 11100 11101]
```

Comment: Почему во 2-ом примере нет запятых и куча пробелов? Что это за структура данных? Вы имели в виду простой `list`?

Comment: лень было ставить

Answer (score 3):

Вы вот это хотели?

```
a = [[0], [1], [10], [11], [100], [101], [110], [111]]
b = [x[0] for x in a]      # [0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111]
```

А можно и так, если у вас не случайный подбор данных в примере

```
b = [int(bin(x)[2:]) for x in range(8)] # [0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111]
```